# Ansible jinja format message in foreach

Tags: ansible, jinja2

SOLVED
I have some problem with parsing output with jinja in ansible. I am trying to parse some output from hashicorp vault module, values what I get from direct call to array and what I get after foreach procedure are different.

When I try to get string from result array through index

```
    - name: Debug2
      debug:
        msg: "{{ current.results[my_idx].secret }}"
      loop: "{{  hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.inventory_hostname', 'defined') | map(attribute='value.inventory_hostname') }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
```

I am getting correct output:

```
TASK [Debug2] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=test1) => {
    "msg": {
        "foo": "variable",
        "test10": "QO9*WsDKzJfj"                                                                                                      
    }
}
```

But when I use construction with foreach for array current.results

```
 - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: " {% for value in current.results %}
                 {% if value.item == item %}
                   {{ value.secret }}
                 {% endif %}
               {% endfor %} "
      loop: "{{  hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.inventory_hostname', 'defined') | map(attribute='value.inventory_hostname') }}"
```

I get this format:

```
TASK [Debug] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=test1) => {
    "msg": "   {'foo': 'variable', 'test10': 'QO9*WsDKzJfj'}         "
}
```

How to make the output the same as without using "for"?

UPD
Ok. I want to rotate passwords in Vault through ansible and send them to specify machines.

1. I generate new password.
2. I am using loop to get all creds for each host through

```
    community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_get in array "current"
        - name: Retrieve current secret
          community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_get:
            path: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{  hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.inventory_hostname', 'defined') | map(attribute='value.inventory_hostname') }}"
          register: current
```

after that I need to save new password through  community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_write with this construct

```
    - name: Update the secret
      vars:
        values_to_update:
          test10: "{{ new_password.data.data.password }}"
      community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_write:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        data: " {% for value in current.results %}
                   {% if value.item == item %}
                      {{ value.secret | combine(values_to_update) }}
                   {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}"

}}"
      loop: "{{  hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.inventory_hostname', 'defined') | map(attribute='value.inventory_hostname') }}"
```

If i use current.results[0].secret instead value.secret | combine(values_to_update) it works, but with value.secret - wrong format

I used this construction with included loop, because data in array "current" without any index.  Here is an example.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "data": {
                "data": {
                    "foo": "variable",
                    "test10": "QO9*WsDKzJfj"
                },
               ....
            },
            "item": "test1",
            "secret": {
                "foo": "variable",
                "test10": "QO9*WsDKzJfj"
            }
        },
        {

            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "data": {
                "data": {
                    "foo2": "variable2",
                    "test10": "4Z01GUkp*yHL"
                }
                ....
            },
            "item": "localhost",
            "secret": {
                "foo": "variable2",
                "test10": "4Z01GUkp*yHL"
            }
        }
```

**UPD. SOLVED**
The solution was easy, just replace {% %} for jinja's loops to {%- and -%}. It disabled extra spaces and get plain string, which I can to use.

Comment: Because debug will pretty print a JSON but what you are constructing with your loop is a string, not a JSON.

Comment: It feels that you are doing an overcomplicated loop and querying for something that could be achieved way more easily. In order to avoid a [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info), could you drscribe what you are trying to achieve? You should also provide an example input data, which, in this case, should include an inventory as you are looping over `hostvars`.

Comment: What is the reason for you to loop on `hostvars` while you could just let Ansible loop over the hosts you targeted in the `hosts` parameter of your playbook?

Comment: A bold assumption is that you are probably missing on the fact that you can delegate tasks to another host still being in the context of the host Ansible acts on: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html

Comment: Solved. The issue was in {% %} for jinja loop. I just replace it with {%- -%}, extra spaces are gone and this contruction ( {{ value.secret | combine(values_to_update) }} ) started to work correctly.